# Finding which region is nearest to which stations in R

Tags: r, proximity, voronoi-thiessen

I have a point dataset of 16 places in Switzerland that looks like these and is called stations

```
stations <- read_csv("station.csv)
view(stations)
```

| Cityid | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 611285.549 | 267664.109 |
| 2 | 600454.843 | 199648.553 |
| 3 | 754069.768 | 225837.065 |
| 4 | 716492.326 | 112276.605 |
| 5 | 782974.270 | 186304.740 |
| 6 | 500013.259 | 117819.944 |
| 7 | 554010.979 | 217120.979 |
| 8 | 538122.750 | 152357.507 |
| 9 | 704699.521 | 113740.950 |
| 10 | 717157.313 | 95810.122 |
| 11 | 666156.604 | 211382.117 |
| 12 | 734356.986 | 277041.847 |
| 13 | 594091.196 | 119770.519 |
| 14 | 683125.786 | 247005.951 |
| 15 | 81150.847 | 720009.498 |
| 16 | 690036.302 | 283496.466 |

I have also a shapefile municipality in Switzerland and their geometry

```
ms_shp <- st_read("CH.shp")
```

Now I would like to create Thiessen polygons to find out which regions belongs to which station according to the shortest distance and to have a list which stations are the nearest to which stations.

I used that code but got an error

```
library('dismo')
points <- matrix(c(stations$x,stations$y), ncol=2)
voronois <- voronoi(points)
spplot(voronoi)
```

The CRS of the datapoints and the shapefile is equal.

The error message is

```
argument not used
```

Is there another method, that I can find which regions are nearest to which stations?

I thought Thiessen polygon is a good method, but maybe another method in R is more useful

Comment: Your goal and Thiessen are incompatible. The best you'll get is polygons overlapping polygons. Calculating the distance of each point to each polygon and choosing the closest is the solution. Doing that in R is left to the arcane-tolerant.

Comment: You could just use `sf::st_disiance`

Comment: You've done `voronois <- voronoi(points)` and `spplot(voronoi)` not `spplot(voronois)` (with an extra `s`).

Comment: If you are using `sf` classes you should use `st_voronoi`.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans I've got my eye in for typos at the moment, so you mean `sf::st_distance`

Comment: @Spacedman thanks, on my phone without glasses on. This is not a good combination for providing accurate information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `stations` into an sf points data frame with same crs as polygons:

```
stations = st_as_sf(stations, coords=c("x","y"), crs=st_crs(ms_shp))
```

create new column in the polygons of the index of the nearest station feature:

```
ms_shp$nearest_station = st_nearest_feature(ms_shp, stations)
```

plot:

```
plot(ms_shp$geom, col=ms_shp$nearest_station, border="white")
plot(stations$geom, add=TRUE, pch=22, col="black", bg="red")
```

[image]

Note "nearest" here is using a distance measure of the nearest distance from point to any point in or on the polygon feature. Some parts of features may be nearer to other stations. If you want to divide the polygon features by this criterion then you do need to apply voronoi polygons and do an intersection.

Comment: how can I change the color, because two stations are in the green area?

Comment: for a better distinguish

Comment: Use a different palette (see `help(palette)`) or use `tmap` for maps. You really need a palette with 16 colours that are distinguishable by human eye, see the `pals` package for lots of possibles. Ask a new question if you get stuck.